# OSRM Error on startup - [warn] Process /usr/bin/osrm-routed could not be locked to RAM

Tags: installation, open-source-routing-machine

When I try to launch [Open Source Routing Machine](http://project-osrm.org/) I am now getting a warning and the service will not start.

```
[warn] Process /usr/bin/osrm-routed could not be locked to RAM
```

I have looked at the discussion at https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/893 however this doesn't seem to offer any suggestions to resolve. I have plenty of RAM available on this server and have been able to start it previously. I have not made any changes to the server since I last started the service successfully only a few days ago.

```
[peterscott@route-optimiser ~]$ /usr/local/bin/osrm-routed --sharedmemory=no /opt/DATA/australia-latest.osrm
[warn] Process /usr/local/bin/osrm-routed could not be locked to RAM
[info] starting up engines, HEAD-HASH-NOTFOUND, compiled at Sep 28 2015, 20:04:28
[info] HSGR file:   "/opt/DATA/australia-latest.osrm.hsgr"
[fatal error] exception: Permission denied
```

Comment: That says its a warning. Perhaps there is some other error? If you haven't made any changes to the server hardware, have you possibly done a kernel or OS upgrade? Does it work if you do `--shared-memory=no`?

Comment: thanks .. the --sharedmemory=no doesn't make a difference .. adding the full error to the question.

Comment: OK, that last bit looks more like the error. What are the permissions on `/opt/DATA/australia-latest.osrm.hsgr`? Which user are you running the routing deamon as?

Comment: OMG - bugger - it was me trying to start to daemon as non-root user. Permissions were ok on the files and execs but it seems that you must be root to obtain the lock on the memory - is there a way to do this without being root?